# Numpy array containing other numpy arrrays unexpectedly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am running this code to generate by training data for a neural net

```
x_train = []
for name in open("datalist.txt", "r").read().split("\n"):
    try:
        img = Image.open("downloads/"+name+"/1.jpg")
        img.resize((400, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        x_train.append(np.array(img))
    except:
        print("load error for: "+name)
x_train = np.array(x_train)
```

and for most small data sets it is a single 4D numpy array but with larger datasets it becomes a 1D numpy array containing 3D numpy arrays

Comment: Is it possible that the images are being processed in different color channels ? Such as Grayscale, RGB, BGR, RGBA etc...

Comment: What do you mean processed? They are all coming from jpgs.

Comment: If all the jpg's contain the same color format, then the problem is different. But if some of them are grayscale or RGB (different than each other), then their pixel matrices would be different. Such as in a grayscale, each matrix cell contains one value (0-255 black to white), in RGBA, each cell (represents a pixel), contains a 4-value array. This may be your issue.

Comment: Looks like it was a combination of that and resizing not working properly. Thank You!